# How to get wordpress api data by language?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, wordpress-rest-api

Let's say I have this api http://someUrlHere.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=19&per_page=20
and I call it with GET method.
How can I choose what language I want to receive the information? It should pe provided in 2 languages. Or how do I find out if it is provided only in English?

Comment: Does your WordPress installation use a plugin to orchestrate delivering content in multiple national languages? This is a function of that plugin. What plugin do you use? Please [edit] your question. Better yet, give this question to the plugin's developer.

Comment: It uses WPML Multilingual CMS and WPML String Translation.  WPML Translation Management is not activated. I haven't worked with WP before so I don't know what these plugins are for.

Answer (score 8):

Activate WPML Translation Management and then you must add

```
lang=en
```

as parameter to your call:

```
http://someUrlHere.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=19&per_page=20&lang=en
```